# Find overlap between 2 integer conversions of hex strings

Tags: r, hex, strtol

i have some area flags in hex format e.g. "090A", "3BFF", "0400", "2025".

In SQL I can use the following syntax to work out the overlap between 2 area flags, for example:

```
SELECT 
STRTOL('090A', 16) as area1
,STRTOL('3BFF', 16) as area2
,STRTOL('090A', 16) & STRTOL('3BFF', 16) as overlap;
```

| area1 | area2 | overlap |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2314 | 15359 | 2314 |

this shows that area1 is fully included in area2.

Another example:

```
SELECT 
STRTOL('0400', 16) as area3
,STRTOL('2025', 16) as area4
,STRTOL('0400', 16) & STRTOL('2025', 16) as overlap;
```

| area3 | area4 | overlap |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1024 | 8229 | 0 |

this shows that there is no overlap between area3 and area4.

I see we can use `R.utils::strtoi` and that gives me the same conversion for each area that I get in SQL.  However if i use the syntax

```
strtoi("0400", 16L) & strtoi("2025", 16L)
```

I get `TRUE` even when there is no overlap.  Is there a way to get the overlap in R using `strtoi` like we can in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `bitwAnd()` to compute the bitwise and:

```
bitwAnd(strtoi("0400", 16L), strtoi("2025", 16L))
## [1] 0
bitwAnd(strtoi("090A", 16L), strtoi("3BFF", 16L))
## [1] 2314
```

The reason that this

```
strtoi("0400", 16L) & strtoi("2025", 16L)
```

gives `TRUE` is the following: `&` is the logical and-operator in R. And numbers larger than 0 are converted to `TRUE`. So your code is equivalent to

```
TRUE & TRUE
```

which evaluates to `TRUE`.